# How to use CO2 tablets for aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium, plants, aquatic-plants

I'm new to live planted aquarium. Recently, while looking for CO<sub>2</sub> system for my 22 liters (about 6 gallons) tank, I came through a product named CO<sub>2</sub> tablets from generic seller. But I don't know the procedure to use this specific product.

If someone has used this kind of stuff before, please give me your suggestions whether to use it or not. If yes, then how to use it?

I don't want my plants to get killed by avoidable mistakes. 
Product link: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Aquarium-CO2-Tablet-Carbon-dioxide-36tab-Planted-Diffuser-plant-AK251-/371350961947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the description there is this:

> - Drop the tablet in different spots of the aquarium, for more even distribution of CO<sub>2</sub>
> - 2 tablets for every 10 gallon of water, dose 2 times a week

So seems like it's ok to just drop them in your tank.

But I've also already seen kits like this where a small basket was included with suction cups, where you could put the tablet in. This might be safer, so your fish won't confuse it with any food tablets.

Also, don't worry about killing your plants. But do keep an eye out for your fishes. High CO<sub>2</sub> means less oxygen in your tank. So if you see your fish gasping for air, you should reduce the dose you add.

On a related note, you can also buy liquid CO<sub>2</sub>. In my nano tank I use EasyLife Carbo. Very good product, and I think in the end it will be cheaper than those tables. Flourish Excel is another product (but I don't have experience with this).

You can also try a DIY setup. I'm using that for my big tank (180 liters) and it works very good. I followed this guide: http://www.hobbykwekers.nl/artikelen/item/co2-verhogen-met-omgekeerd-bakje - it is in Dutch, but pictures are clear and you can use google translate. And if you google it, I'm sure you'll find similar guides in English. That reversed container makes sure you don't get too much CO<sub>2</sub> in your tank (that container surface should be roughly 10 % of your tank surface).

For my nano tank I found it difficult to get a decent CO<sub>2</sub> production rate. It seemed like a lot of the CO<sub>2</sub> went to waste because of the small container.

But if you play around with the mixture you might find something that works for you (less sugar and yeast).